# Altimeter disagreement. What's the crew procedure to deal with that?

Tags: safety, airline-operations, flight-instruments, altimeter

The crew is facing a situation, in which, the altimeters indicate different altitude (the port and starboard ones - cpt´s and FO´s). Is there any procedure to perform an IFR landing?
If we consider a light aircraft, what the crew will do?

Comment: Light aircraft rarely have more than 1 Altimeter

Comment: @Jamiec The PA28s I fly have two altimeters. The secondary one is tucked down next to the ammeter and mags, and takes its input pressure from inside the cockpit rather than the external static pressure tube.

Answer (score 3):

Since you describe a captain and FO, I'm going to assume that you are asking about a larger aircraft, like say an airliner or business jet.

Part of the certification of these types of aircraft require them to have a third (standby) altimeter in addition to the two primary altimeters.

When there is a discrepancy, the typical procedure (keep in mind that a pilot should always follow the manufacturers checklist in these situations) is to cross-check the three altimeters and find the two that agree so that the bad one is then excluded.