# What is the correct crew procedure for an unreliable airspeed alert?

Tags: safety, airline-operations, flight-instruments, airspeed

When the crew receives "airspeed disagree" message on the primary flight displays, they may face some hazardous situation.
Is there any procedure, using a table containing pitch, power, altitude and weight, to avoid stall, for example?

Comment: This has the exact same answer as [your other question about altimeters](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24737/altimeter-disagreement-whats-the-crew-procedure-to-deal-with-that), so you may just want to ask one about "unreliable flight instruments" instead of one for each of the different instruments...

Comment: TURN ON THE PITOT HEAT!

Answer (score 12):

As you probably know this is the situation that occurred for [AF-447 (Rio-Paris)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_France_Flight_447) on June 2009. From the [BEA report](https://www.bea.aero/docspa/2009/f-cp090601.en/pdf/f-cp090601.en.pdf):

> The accident resulted from the following succession of events:
>
> - Temporary inconsistency between the measured airspeeds, likely following the obstruction of the Pitot probes by ice crystals that led
>   in particular to autopilot disconnection and a reconfiguration to
>   alternate law, [...]
> - The crew not making the connection between the loss of indicated airspeeds and the appropriate procedure,

This mistake happened previously. From the same report:

> Four crews did not identify the unreliable airspeed  situation: in two
> cases, the crews concluded that there was an inconsistency between the
> angles of attack; in the two other cases, the crew considered that the
> speeds were erroneous rather than unreliable.

Then the procedure that should be used in case of unreliable airspeed:

> The philosophy for processing the anomaly is described in the
> “UNRELIABLE AIRSPEED INDICATION / ADR CHECK PROCEDURE” that is in
> Flight Manual (AFM) and transcribed in the Airbus FCOM and the Air
> France Operations Manual.

[image]

This procedure which is to be known without the support of the documentation gives time to retrieve data from the documentation (this is what you wanted to know):

[image]

See also:

- [Unreliable Airspeed Indications](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Unreliable_Airspeed_Indications) on SKYbrary.

Comment: What does "THRUST RED ALT" mean?

Comment: @Ben: [Thrust reduction altitude](http://www.flaps2approach.com/journal/2013/6/29/avoiding-confusion-acceleration-height-thrust-reduction-heig.html). The altitude at which the pilot reduces thrust after take-off.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me now, thanks