# Which company manufactures the air data system on the Boeing 787-9 'Dreamliner'

Tags: boeing, pitot-static, sensors

I'm asking specifically about the manufacturer and model of the Pitot probes/tubes that provide the pilots with current air speed readings.

Pretty sure it's either UTC or Honeywell but can't find anything definitive online.

P.S - Is there any evidence of this technology being improved? Especially since [Air France flight 447](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_France_Flight_447), and more recently [Lion Air 610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion_Air_Flight_610), where in both cases the pilots lost control of the aircraft due to inaccurate airspeed measurements.

Comment: There is zero evidence at this time that the Lion Air flight had inaccurate airspeed measurements. Only irresponsible people speculating.

Comment: Oh is /r/aviation spilling over here?

Comment: For the purposes of this discussion it’s safe for us to entertain the likelihood that this accident was in part caused by inaccurate airspeed readings.

Comment: "*in both cases the pilots lost control of the aircraft due to inaccurate airspeed measurements*". For AF447 this is a simplification. Most of the time during the event, speed indication was reliable. Transient unreliable airspeed is something the crews are trained [to identify and deal with](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/34855/3201). Lack of proper training and inefficient cockpit management are more the causes of improper manual mode reactions which led to the tragedy, as pointed out by [BEA in their report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_France_Flight_447#Final_report).

Comment: @mins I completely agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boeing procured the avionics for the B787 in "packages". Air data was part of the "Navigation Package" which included in addition to air data, IRUs, nav radios, GPS sensors, and the FMS software.

Honeywell was selected as the supplier for the Nav package. So they provided the air data system.  I don't know what specific system they supplied.