# Could TCAS be used as a backup source for position, attitude or air data?

Tags: aircraft-design, avionics, tcas

Given the number of incidents related to freezing pitot tubes, is there any current/planned implementation to infer aircraft position/speed/attitude/bearing based on TCAS data as a last resort data point? If not, is this at least doable?

Even if TCAS gives only relative data, one may correlate the data at the last moment before pitot data are lost to assist in dead reckoning.

**Edit**: I am not sure if my question has been misunderstood, or that I am misinterpreting the answers. The question is more like inferring current aircraft's data *from* transponders of surrounding aircrafts. Let's suppose at time $t_1$ I have planes A, B, and C within my TCAS range. I will possess information regarding their bearing, distance, speed, **and** altitude. At time $t_2$, even without my own altimeter, I can *at least* infer my own vertical speed using trigonometry. A, B, C are like ocean currents, a background moving together with me. If I know enough information about them, depending on what TCAS's underlying data stream provides, I can probably infer my own position, altitude, speed, and heading. From my limited understanding, TCAS bearing, distance, and speed are relative to me. However if I have not mistaken, despite what is shown on the screen, altitude is absolute measurement from the other planes' altimeter. One side fixed on a similar triangle, you'll get the rest.

Comment: Indeed it is amazing, the possibilities in FMS software development.  I would think ADS-B could provide more data to the FMS than the limited scope of TCAS.  Unless there's at least three other aircraft within scope, there'd be no data.  Oceanic service would be nill for either.  Here's FlightAware's coverage of ground-based ADS-B receivers:  http://flightaware.com/adsb/coverage

Comment: GPS might be an option, combined with jetstream and wind plotting.

Comment: And EGPWS contains a map of all of earth and knows the aircraft position and terrain altitude.

Comment: GPS inferred data won't give you airspeed

Comment: @STWilson  You've got it backwards.  The FMS provides much the data that is broadcast via ADS-B Out.  While it is possible to send ADS-B In data to the FMS there are no FMS functions that can make use of the data.  There are some proposed "Surveillance Applications" that use the ADS-B In data that might have an interface to the FMS, but what it can and is allowed to do has to be defined and agreed upon by a large number of organizations.  The FMS just guides the plane along the flight plan and the flight plan has to stay in sync with the ATC clearance.

Comment: @Gerry  I refer to the increasing potential of flight management systems, specifically the FMS software, to processes data from the variety of IO devices like GPS, air data/system computers, AHARS, transponders, ADS-B, XM-feeds, et al.  I refer to FMS that today does more than output to the flight director.

Comment: @STWilson Since my day job involves developing said FMS, I can authoritatively say that while the FMS does process data from a large number of sensors, it does not receive any input from ADS-B nor is any planned in the near term.  The FMS does have an output to the ADS-B Out function (usually the Mode S transponder) that provides "intent" data (aircraft state and flight plan), but that's it.

Comment: If there is something to use when pitots are blocked, this is the attitude indicator. Just keep [the recommended attitude](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24739/) corresponding to the throttle position, as written in the FCOM.

Comment: Question edited with clarification. Hope it makes more sense. Chiming in the discussion above, it is quite sad that despite so many data sources are available, FMS fails to integrate them.

Comment: @Mobile Computing, understand that the TCAS sensor gives:1. Distance (rather accurately, using transponder return time), 2. Bearing (rather crudely and 3. Pressure altitude of the observed aircraft.  Do we agree that this is the fundamental capability of the TCAS sensor?

Comment: @mongo Yes, and?

Comment: If we agree that is the capability of the sensor then there is no additional information available which would assist in DR or navigation.  Integration of OTHER sensor data (GPS, ADS-B etc might yield usable data, but the bottom line is that TCAS alone provides no useful data for dead reckoning. While there might be an instant where you suggest that an inference could be made, most failures are not detected instantly, and by the time they are detected other aircraft have moved.

Answer (score 6):

Can TCAS assist in dead reckoning?

First, understand that TCAS runs off secondary (transponder) radar data. Essentially your aircraft with TCAS is like ATC radar, interrogating other transponders, getting their pressure altitude and getting their bearing from your aircraft.  That data combined is processed to create threat advisories.

If displayed on a moving map, the moving map is typically fed positional data for your aircraft from GPS, and the TCAS alert data is overlayed onto the map.

So to address your question, TCAS only provides data about transponders relative to your aircraft.  TCAS does not determine where you are, or where you are going. (Depending upon your display it might appear that way, but that is not part of the TCAS system.)

So the answer to your question is no, TCAS does not effectively create a secondary navigation capability.

Addendum #1
TCAS can only sense altitude through the host aircraft's static port, so if it is iced over, TCAS has invalid altitude information.

TCAS does not sense other air data, such as pitot pressure information (airspeed).

TCAS does not know the host aircraft's position.  Any positional information in TCAS is derived from pressure altitude information the host and all interrogated transponders.  If the host static port is obscured, the information on threats will be invalid, because TCAS displays relative to the host pressure altitude.

In other words, there is no absolute positional information, and all TCAS information is relative to the current host aircraft, and derived from the secondary beacons of interrogated aircraft transponders.

Answer (score 0):

Afair:

The ATC/SSR antena can barely discern azimuth on the responses, and effectivelly no elevation data.The only accurate info from TCAS is distance to intruder (and closure rate). This means you have some ideea of the *direction* of the intruder (not accurate enough mind you ,which is why RAs have only vertical guidance), but no real means of determining their *relative altitude* to you.

So basically you know you have another aircraft somewhere to your left, at FL110... how could you infer your altitude from that?

GPS altitude is another issue, and ,in fact, backup altitude from GPS does appear on some (A320s at least) PFDs when all ADR data is lost .

Later edit: if you bring ADS-B into the question, with a/c broadcasting their lat/long and flight level, you know the distance from your a/c to these points and can draw a sphere arround each of these points, at their intersection you can triangulate your position (including altittude) assuming you have enough traffic arround (min 3). Mathematically ,yes, posssible, but once you factor in the delays in ASD-B, the rounding errors in transmitting FLs, etc the accuracy would be horrible probablly within 100s and 1000s of feet